# Pyomo - implicit conversion of pyomo numeric value to integer

Tags: optimization, pyomo

I am trying to optimize a pyomo abstract model (m). The model has a (integer) parameter called `a`. I want to calculate another integer value while constructing a model. Let the other variable be `c = a*(a-1)/2`. And I want an array of binary variables of size `c`
For this I am writing the following lines -

```
#File - test.py#
from pyomo.environ import *
m = AbstractModel()
m.a = Param()
c = m.a*(m.a-1)/2
m.var = Var(range(1,c), within=Binary)
m.obj = Objective(expr = 0)

#File - data.dat#
param a := 5 ;
```

To solve this I ran - `pyomo solve test.py data.dat --solver=glpk`

After running this I get the following error:

```
Implicit conversion of Pyomo NumericValue type `<class 
'pyomo.core.kernel.expr_coopr3._ProductExpression'>' to an integer 
is disabled. This error is often the result of using Pyomo components as 
arguments to one of the Python built-in math 
module functions when defining expressions. Avoid this error by using Pyomo-
provided math functions.
```

I think the error comes when I try to take `range(1,c)`. Correct me if I am wrong.

I have Python 2.7.12, Pyomo-5.3 (CPython-2.7.12 on Linux). I will have to ask the installation method to someone as I got it installed, so it might take time. I will update the installation method once I ask the person who installed it.

Thanks.

Comment: Your example does not raise any error using either master or the current release (5.3).  Please provide the following basic information: platform, python interpreter & version, pyomo version, installation method, and a (minimal) example that demonstrated the error.

Comment: Please have a look at the changes @jsiirola. Thanks

Comment: Your example still doesn't produce the error you report.  This would be simpler with a *complete* example (e.g., how are you declaring `m.a`?), the complete error (your "(something here)" is actually useful information!), the platform, python interpreter & version, pyomo version, and installation method.

Comment: Thanks for your patience @jsiirola. Please have a look at the updated question. I tried to answer your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things going on here:

1. You are evaluating a Param before it is defined.
2. You are implicitly casting a Pyomo expression to an integer.

The root of the problem is that you are treating an Abstract Model as if it was a Concrete Model.  For Abstract models, when you declare `m.a`, you are only declaring the *existence* of a Parameter `a`.  Python then continues to parse and execute the rest of your model.  When it hits `c = m.a*(m.a-1)/2`, Python generates a Pyomo expression tree representing the right-hand-side.  Finally, when it gets to `m.var = Var(range(1,c), within=Binary)`, Python first executes the `range(1,c)` before calling the `Var()` constructor.  `range` (a Python function) casts its arguments to `int` before generating the range list.  That cast is what is generating the error.

You *could* get around that error by explicitly evaluating the value of the expression (`c`) with the (Pyomo) `value(c)` function.  However, that will generate a different (perhaps more informative) error that you are evaluating a Param `a` before it has been constructed.  This is because at this point the model is still abstract, and the data file that provides a value for `a` has not even been read.

The solution is to make an explicit *Pyomo* `Set` that will act as a placeholder for the expression and will not be constructed until the rest of the model is constructed (that is, the evaluation of the expression `c` is deferred until the value for `a` is available).  For example:

```
from pyomo.environ import *
m = AbstractModel()
m.a = Param()
c = m.a*(m.a-1)/2
# Note that RangeSet includes the upper bound, whereas range stops one short
m.IDX = RangeSet(1,c-1) 
m.var = Var(m.IDX, within=Binary)
m.obj = Objective(expr = 0)
```